# Multi-dimensional array / creating a survey

Tags: php, arrays, traversal

I have an array like this:

```
$survey = array(
        'Category1' => array(
            'Question1' => array(
                'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
            ),
            'Question2' => array(
                'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
            )
        ),
        'Category2' => array(
            'Question1' => array(
                'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
            ),
            'Question2' => array(
                'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
            )
        )
    );
```

This array is in practice much larger. The requirement is 3 questions per page. My thought was to store which category and question I'm currently on. For example category 0, question 2. Then check to see if `array_key_exists` and if so, display, if not, increment and try again. As you might have guessed, categories and questions don't have keys (at least not numeric ones for me to loop through). So using an index is, as far as I know, is out of the question. How can I dynamically display 3 questions per page and automatically get the next 3 questions for the next page without knowing what the value is for category2, for example. How can I traverse/target this?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: How can you can have an array with Category1 as the key twice?

Comment: I assume is probably a typo. :).

Comment: is there any reason you can't store these in a database? would be much easier.

Comment: My mistake, I took out all the real data and replaced it manually so it's easier to read. I will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data seems fairly static so i would suggest changing the data format :)

Change the array into something like:

```
$survey = array(
   array( 'name' = > 'Category1', 
          'questions' => array(
            array(
               'name' => 'Question1',
               'opts' => array(
                  'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
               )
            ),
                    array(
               'name' => 'Question2',
               'opts' => array(
                  'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
               )
            )
        ),
   array( 'name' = > 'Category2', 
          'questions' => array(

            array(
               'name' => 'Question1',
               'opts' => array(
                  'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
               )
            ),
            array(
               'name' => 'Question2',
               'opts' => array(
                  'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
               )
            )
        )
    );
```

And you can use integer indexes then. Just remember 2 number (the category index and the question index inside the category. And just increment until end of array in each case.

Php is not my strongest language so the code above might look strange to a native php programmer. However the root cause of OP's difficulties is the inability to easily create an interator type object. This is because of the fact that the key based array have a "strange" order given by their hash map nature. Change the nature and allow yourself to build an interator like object (aka an array index).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an associative array (aka hash), there is no order to it. Each question and each category need to have the next question/category key with them. After that, see link-list algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

My be `array_keys()` function will help you? You will iterate keys array (to get next keys).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $survey = array(
    'Category1' => array(
        'Question1' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question2' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question3' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question4' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        )
    ),
    'Category 2' => array(
        'Question1' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question2' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        )
    ),
    'Category 3' => array(
        'Question1' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question2' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
        'Question3' => array(
            'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'
        ),
    )
  );

function fetchQuestions($survey, $page, $perPage = 3)
{
  $results = Array();

  $nCount = 0; $nRead = 0; $nIndex = $page * $perPage;
  foreach ($survey as $CategoryName => $Questions)
  {
    foreach ($Questions as $Question => $Options)
    {
      if ($nCount >= $nIndex && $nRead < $perPage)
      {
        if (!isset($results[$CategoryName]))
          $results[$CategoryName] = Array();

        $results[$CategoryName][$Question] = $Options;

        $nRead++;
      }
      $nCount++;
    }
  }
  return $results;
}
echo '<html><body><pre>';
var_dump(fetchQuestions($survey,0));
var_dump(fetchQuestions($survey,1));
var_dump(fetchQuestions($survey,2));
echo '</pre></body></html>';
```

?>

And the output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Category1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Question1"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
    ["Question2"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
    ["Question3"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["Category1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Question4"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
  }
  ["Category 2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Question1"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
    ["Question2"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["Category 3"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Question1"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
    ["Question2"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
    ["Question3"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Option1"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Option2"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Option3"
    }
  }
}
```

There's my bid. Returns an array similar to your original array with the questions that should be displayed on that specific page.

**If you want a more visual representation:**

```
echo '<html><body>';
$page = 0;
while (count($matches = fetchQuestions($survey,$page++)) > 0)
{
  echo '<div style="background-color:#CCC;">';
  echo '<h2>Page '.$page.'</h2>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($matches as $Category => $Questions)
  {
    echo '<li><strong>'.$Category.'</strong>:<ul>';
    foreach ($Questions as $Question => $Options)
    {
      echo '<li><u>'.$Question.'</u><ul>';
      foreach ($Options as $Option)
        echo '<li>'.$Option.'</li>';
      echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</div>';
}
echo '</body></html>';
```